# About round function issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im trying to sum and round all the results from `interview_sum`,`other_sum`,`edu_attain2_sum`,`experience2_sum`,`trainings2_sum`,`eligibility2_sum`.

with this line of code: but when i run the query i got an error in this line....can anyone help me whats wrong?

```
ROUND(SUM(interview_sum,other_sum,edu_attain2_sum,experience2_sum,trainings2_sum,eligibility2_sum)) AS final_total_sum,
```

current query:

```
    ROUND((SELECT SUM(t2.inttotal)
     FROM app_interview2 AS t2 
     WHERE t2.atic = t.atic)/7,1)
     AS interview_sum,

    ROUND((SELECT SUM(o2.ototal)
     FROM other_app2 AS o2 
     WHERE o2.oaic = t.atic)/7,1)
     AS other_sum,

    ROUND((SELECT SUM(s1.edu_attain2)
     FROM qual_stan2 AS s1 
     WHERE s1.oaic2 = t.atic)/7,1)
     AS edu_attain2_sum,

    ROUND((SELECT SUM(s2.experience2)
     FROM qual_stan2 AS s2 
     WHERE s2.oaic2 = t.atic)/7,1)
     AS experience2_sum,

    ROUND((SELECT SUM(s3.trainings2)
     FROM qual_stan2 AS s3 
     WHERE s3.oaic2 = t.atic)/7,1)
     AS trainings2_sum,

    ROUND((SELECT SUM(s4.eligibility2)
     FROM qual_stan2 AS s4 
     WHERE s4.oaic2 = t.atic)/7,1)
     AS eligibility2_sum,

    ROUND(SUM(interview_sum,other_sum,edu_attain2_sum,experience2_sum,trainings2_sum,eligibility2_sum)) AS final_total_sum,

    t.atid,
    t.atic,
    t.atname,
    t.region,
    t.town,
    t.uniq_id,
    t.position,
    t.salary_grade,
    t.salary
    FROM app_interview2 AS t
    WHERE t.uniq_id = 'ADAS3-1493-2013'
    GROUP BY t.atname HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.atic)
```

Comment: ...and the error is...?!

Comment: You can only put one column name inside `SUM`. If you want to add two columns together, use `+`.

Comment: @Barmar the thing is they not columms they are title from the previous sum results.

Comment: @Barmar i want to add all the titles so that i can have a final result

Comment: Same thing, you add aliases with `+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `+`:

```
SELECT *,
    ROUND(interview_sum +
          other_sum +
          edu_attain2_sum +
          experience2_sum +
          trainings2_sum +
          eligibility2_sum) AS final_total_sum
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROUND((SELECT SUM(t2.inttotal)
         FROM app_interview2 AS t2 
         WHERE t2.atic = t.atic)/7,1)
         AS interview_sum,

        ROUND((SELECT SUM(o2.ototal)
         FROM other_app2 AS o2 
         WHERE o2.oaic = t.atic)/7,1)
         AS other_sum,

        ROUND((SELECT SUM(s1.edu_attain2)
         FROM qual_stan2 AS s1 
         WHERE s1.oaic2 = t.atic)/7,1)
         AS edu_attain2_sum,

        ROUND((SELECT SUM(s2.experience2)
         FROM qual_stan2 AS s2 
         WHERE s2.oaic2 = t.atic)/7,1)
         AS experience2_sum,

        ROUND((SELECT SUM(s3.trainings2)
         FROM qual_stan2 AS s3 
         WHERE s3.oaic2 = t.atic)/7,1)
         AS trainings2_sum,

        ROUND((SELECT SUM(s4.eligibility2)
         FROM qual_stan2 AS s4 
         WHERE s4.oaic2 = t.atic)/7,1)
         AS eligibility2_sum,
        t.atid,
        t.atic,
        t.atname,
        t.region,
        t.town,
        t.uniq_id,
        t.position,
        t.salary_grade,
        t.salary
    FROM app_interview2 AS t
    WHERE t.uniq_id = 'ADAS3-1493-2013'
    GROUP BY t.atname 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.atic)) subq
```

Comment: but i got an error ([Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'interview_sum' in 'field list')

Comment: Isn't that one of the aliases in the subquery that you showed in the second part of your question?

Comment: If you post the entire query I may be able to clean it up. I assumed the rest of your query was OK, and you just needed to know how to write this one part.

Answer (score 1):

`SUM` only accepts a single expression as an argument. You need to do:

```
SUM(field1 + field2 + field3 + ....)
```

Comment: He doesn't need SUM, he already used that to calculate the fields.

Comment: Doesn't matter - his SQL is fully broken because of the mis-use of SUM() anyways.

Comment: @Marc B if you look carefully to my post and my query...i want to add are not fields...those are titles from my other results.

Comment: @user3311499: Doesn't matter. `SUM()` cannot accept multiple arguments, e.g. `SUM(a,b,c)` is 3 expressions and 3 separate arguments. One **EXPRESSION** only. Each `,`-separated argument is a separate expression. `SUM(a+b+c)` will calculate a+b+c and send in that result as the single expression argument to SUM().